# How do I fix this regex to match the strings I want?

Tags: regex

I need to find out specific user names that meet a certain - albeit rather wide - criteria. My knowledge at regex is very limited so while my regex constructs did match what I wanted, they also matched about everything else. Can you help me?

The requirements for a valid match are:

- string length: exactly 7 characters
- contains only alphanumeric characters, mixed upper and lower case, or numbers 0-9
- contains at least one number 0-9, can be more than that but never 3 in a row
- not all upper case (can be all lower case but never upper case)

Unfortunately, the numbers can be anywhere in the string, and the alphanumeric characters can also be any combination.

Here is an excerpt of the data I need to match:

- cgxh21o *
- crittaz
- Mist246
- nOnameR
- Gorebag
- pu50pce *
- rmygy62 *
- aeifnz0 *
- orp5k1v *
- okn5nvr *

The ones marked with * are the ones I want to match. The remaining ones are valid and must not be included.

Is this even possible using regex?

My last attempt was:

```
/[a-z{0,}A-Z{0,}0-9{1,}]{7}+
```

but then I found user names that didn't follow that notation at all (more than one number) so it didn't work.

Comment: Looking at what you've described, why do crittaz and Gorebag or nOnameR or Mist246 not match? Is there also a requirement that there must be 1 or more digit? Or fewer than 3?

Comment: crittaz shouldn't match because it doesn't include a digit. Same with Gorebag and nOnamer - no digits. Mist246 would match, unfortunately, but that's a false positive I am willing to work with (it looks valid). I would be happy to exclude *most* names that don't match - right now I am facing to manually sift through 110k entries by hand and I want to filter that down to an amount I can manage.

However, it looks like there are very rarely three digits in a row. Maybe that's something to work with.

Comment: OK, can you edit your question to include a rule that there must be 1 or more digit? That will help us a lot.

Comment: Yep, I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a relatively short and simple regex that will work:

```
(?=(^.{7}$))(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*\d{3})
```

**[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/nvNxRx/1)**

Explanation:

- `(?=(^.{7}$))`  check that there's exactly 7 characters (and capture them)
- `(?=.*[a-z])`    at least one lower case letter
- `(?=.*\d)`         at least one digit
- `(?!.*\d{3})`    there isn't 3 digits in a row anywhere

Here's a Python demo:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(?=(^.{7}$))(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*\d{3})")

ls = ["cgxh21o", "crittaz", "Mist246", "nOnameR", "Gorebag",
      "pu50pce", "rmygy62", "aeifnz0", "orp5k1v", "okn5nvr",
      "OKN5NVR", "short1", "aeifnz0aaaaaa", "12CeE12"]

for elem in ls:
    print(elem, bool(re.search(pattern, elem)))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> cgxh21o True
> crittaz False
> Mist246 False
> nOnameR False
> Gorebag False
> pu50pce True
> rmygy62 True
> aeifnz0 True
> orp5k1v True
> okn5nvr True
> OKN5NVR False
> short1 False
> aeifnz0aaaaaa False
> 12CeE12 True
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You could use lookahead assertions:

```
^(?=[^a-z\s]*[a-z])(?=[^\d\s]*\d)(?!.*\d{3})[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[^a-z\s]*[a-z])` Assert a lowercase char a-z
- `(?=[^\d\s]*\d)` Assert a digit
- `(?!.*\d{3})` Assert not 3 digits in a row
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}` Match 7 times any of the listed
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6bjY3J/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility based on your updated question:

```
^(?![a-zA-Z]{7}|.*[0-9]{3}.*|[A-Z0-9]{7})([a-zA-Z0-9]){7}$
```

Doesn't match

```
  crittaz
  nOnameR
  Gorebag
  ABCDEFG
  aBCDEFG
  1234567
  Mist246
  ABCDEF7
```

Matches

```
  cgxh21o
  pu50pce
  rmygy62
  aeifnz0
  orp5k1v
  okn5nvr
```

There's probably a number of ways to do this. This one looks for 7 alphanumeric, but not if there's only 7 alphabetic, not if there's only uppercase and numbers, and not if there's 3 digits in a row...